# Test data features not matching with training data features for OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am new to the OneHotEncoder and trying to solve a classification problem with it.
However, my test dataset is giving me errors in terms of having a different shape. I am having the same columns in training and testing dataset. Here is my code:

```
X = pd.read_csv('Svr_good.csv') #Training data
Xt = pd.read_csv('svr_test.csv') #Testing data

X = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])
Xt = Xt.select_dtypes(include=[object])
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
X_4 = Xt.apply(le.fit_transform)

enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc1 = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X_2)
enc1.fit(X_4)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(X_2).toarray()
onehotlabels1 = enc1.transform(X_4).toarray()

numpy_array = onehotlabels
X = numpy_array[:, 1:]
y = numpy_array[:, 0]

lm = LinearSVC()
model = lm.fit(X, y)
predictions = lm.predict(onehotlabels1)
print predictions
```

The above code gives me an error of feature mismatch. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are fitting on X and predicting on onehotlabels1, but X has one less column.

Does it work if you change `X = numpy_array[:, 1:]` for `X = numpy_array`?

Comment: No it does not help. I updated the code a bit as well.

Comment: Can you share the exact error message and the result of `print(Xt.shape)` and `print(X.shape)` after you've selected the dtypes please?

Comment: print (Xt.shape) = (20, 6) & print (X.shape) = (28283, 6). Error message is: ValueError: X has 69 features per sample; expecting 40988

Comment: onehotlabels1 is the result of a different onehotencoder, hence it does not have the same number of features. Does it work if you replace `onehotlabels1 = enc1.transform(X_4).toarray()` with `onehotlabels1 = enc.transform(X_4).toarray()`,  and replace `predictions = lm.predict(onehotlabels1)` with `predictions = lm.predict(onehotlabels1[:, :1])`? If it doesn't can you share the error and tell me what you are trying to achieve?